# Not able to connect MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-compass

I am not able to connect my server in MongoDB Compass. I am trying to connect by identity file. I am providing hostname username and file.
I got:

> 'Error creating SSH Tunnel: Timed out while waiting for forwardOut'

What does it mean?

Comment: Few things to note according to the image. Some times the pem file will have a pass phrase, if so dont forget it add it. And the server cannot be pinged. So make sure whether the server is running.

Comment: I guess pass phrase in not there. Because I can able to logged in via termnal to that mongodb. But I am facing issue on MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 21):

Hi, krl! I was getting the exact same error from MongoDB Compass Community 1.11.1 while trying to connect through an SSH tunnel, with a ppk file protected by a passphrase.

Are you putting your remote server IP or domain name in the first field (hostname)? That was my mistake.

What solved it for me was setting the `Hostname` field (the first one on top) to `localhost` instead of remote server IP or domain name. Put your domain/IP only on the field SSH Hostname.

I hope it helps.

Comment: And where to put my shh hostname??

Comment: Hey, @MahmoudEzzat. Set the field SSH Tunnel to "Use Identity File", then the SSH Hostname field (along with several others) will appear. Valid for v1.18.0